# WPF layout with several fixed height parts and certain parts relative to window size

Tags: wpf, gridview, layout, telerik, stackpanel

At moment my main layout consists of vertically oriented stack panel and it looks like this:

Root StackPanel

- StackPanel - fixed Height 150
  (horizontal orientation)
- StackPanel  - relative Height must be
  behalf of free space left on screen 
  (but at least 150 px). Used by Telerik
  GridView Control, if I don't specify Height or MaxHeight Telerik GridView Height becomes very large and does not fit my window.
- StackPanel - fixed Height 100
  (horizontal orientation)
- StackPanel - relative Height must be
  half of free space left on screen
  (but at least 150 px). Used by Telerik
  GridView Control,  if I don't specify Height or MaxHeight Telerik GridView Height becomes very large and does not fit my window.
- StackPanel - fixed Height 100
  (horizontal orientation)

The view must totally fit available screen size.

The problem is that I don't understand how to make certain areas of my view resize depending on available screen size.

Is there is easy way to solve it, or should I be binding to Window height property and doing math?

Thank You very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont have the telerik controls to hand to test so this is off the top of my head - can you not use a grid as the basis of your control rather than a stackpanel like this? - if this is still a problem then post some code up and we can take a look at what you are trying to achieve.

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="150"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>            
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" />
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  />
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" />
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  />
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="4" />
    </Grid>
```